# Are '' books are too many" and "cats are not enough" correct to say?

Tags: grammar

My teacher told me that it should be like "two cups of coffee is too much" and I wonder if it applies here? I understand it's common to say "there're too many books" and "there are enough cats". so my question is : are "books are too many"  and  "cats are not enough" correct to say? and what should I say if i put "many” and "enough" at the end of sentence.

Comment: I would consider "Books are too numerous (in this house)". You need something more to follow "Cats are not enough to ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sentences are good:

> Two cups of coffee is too much.
>
> One cup of coffee is too much.

You can't really say these:

> Cup of coffee is too much. **[bad]**
>
> Cups of coffee is too much. **[bad]**

Likewise, you cannot say these sentences:

> Books are too many. **[bad]**
>
> Cats are not enough. **[bad]**

You *can* use this construction if you specify a quantity for the subject of each sentence. For example, these are all good:

> A thousand books is too many.
>
> One book is too many.
>
> A dozen cats is not enough.
>
> Zero cats is not enough.

Comment: oh! can i say " this amount of water is not enough" it implies  quantity

Comment: Yes, you can say ***This amount of water is not enough.*** Or ***A glass of water is not enough.***

Comment: oh also i have another quesion. Is "The water is in small amount" correct?

Comment: No, you have to specify some kind of quantity or amount as a modifier for the subject. And also, you wouldn't say **is in small amount** ever. Instead people say **Water is in short supply** or **Ten gallons of water is *a* small amount**.